# AWS Sagemaker batch transform with JSON input filter

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have a custom Sagemaker instance on a NLP task and trying to run a batch transform on the following json file
{"id":123, "features":"This is a test message"}'
and im looking to output the following:
{"id":123,"SageMakerOutput":spam}

Here's my batch transform code:

```
transformer = sklearn.transformer(instance_count=1,
                                  instance_type='local',
                                  accept='application/json',
                                  output_path="s3://spam-detection-messages-output/json_examples")

transformer.transform("s3://spam-detection-messages/json_examples", content_type='application/json', input_filter="$.features", join_source="Input", output_filter="$['features', SageMakerOutput']")
print('Waiting for transform job: ' + transformer.latest_transform_job.job_name)
transformer.wait()
```

According to this document,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform-data-processing.html#batch-transform-data-processing-examples
i should be able to grab the "features" object using input_filter,
however, it grabs the entire json payload. and only outputs the prediction

I'm also including my training code

```
import argparse
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import io
import json

from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.stop_words import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import numpy as np

import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')

stemmer = PorterStemmer()
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

def remove_stop_words(words):
    result = [i for i in words if i not in ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS]
    return result

def word_stemmer(words):
    return [stemmer.stem(o) for o in words]

def word_lemmatizer(words):
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(o) for o in words]

def remove_characters(words):
    return [word for word in words if len(word)> 1]

def clean_token_pipeline(words):
    cleaning_utils = [remove_stop_words, word_lemmatizer]
    for o in cleaning_utils:
        words = o(words)
    return words

def process_text(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    X_train = [word_tokenize(o) for o in X_train]
    X_test = [word_tokenize(o) for o in X_test]

    X_train = [clean_token_pipeline(o) for o in X_train]
    X_test = [clean_token_pipeline(o) for o in X_test]

    X_train = [" ".join(o) for o in X_train]
    X_test = [" ".join(o) for o in X_test]

    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test

def convert_to_feature(raw_tokenize_data):
    raw_sentences = [' '.join(o) for o in raw_tokenize_data]
    return vectorizer.transform(raw_sentences)

def _npy_loads(data):
    """
    Deserializes npy-formatted bytes into a numpy array
    """
    stream = io.BytesIO(data)
    return np.load(stream)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # Sagemaker specific arguments. Defaults are set in the environment variables.
    parser.add_argument('--output-data-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR'])
    parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR'])
    parser.add_argument('--train', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN'])

    args = parser.parse_args()

    train_data = pd.read_csv(args.train+"/spamAssassin_min.csv", index_col=0)
    train_data.dropna(inplace=True)
    print(train_data.head())

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data['message'], train_data['label'], test_size = 0.2, random_state = 1)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = process_text(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)

    X_train = [o.split(" ") for o in X_train]
    X_test = [o.split(" ") for o in X_test]

    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    raw_sentences = [' '.join(o) for o in X_train]
    vectorizer.fit(raw_sentences)

#     print("saving transformer to {}".format(args.model_dir))
    joblib.dump(vectorizer, os.path.join(args.model_dir, "vectorizer.joblib"))

    x_train_features = convert_to_feature(X_train)
    x_test_features = convert_to_feature(X_test)

    clf = GaussianNB()
    clf.fit(x_train_features.toarray(),y_train)

    y_true, y_pred = y_test, clf.predict(x_test_features.toarray())
    print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))

    joblib.dump(clf, os.path.join(args.model_dir, "model.joblib"))

def model_fn(model_dir):
    """Deserialized and return fitted model

    Note that this should have the same name as the serialized model in the main method
    """
    clf = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.joblib"))
#     print("model loaded {}".format(clf))
    return clf

def input_fn(request_body, request_content_type):
    print("** input_fn**")
    print("request_body:{} request_content_type:{}".format(request_body, request_content_type))
    if request_content_type == "text/plain":
        #convert to string
        message = str(request_body)
        return message
    elif request_content_type == "application/json":
        request_body_json = json.loads(request_body)
#         print("json {}".format(request_body_json))
        return request_body_json['features']
    elif request_content_type == "application/x-npy":
        return " ".join(_npy_loads(request_body))
    else:
        # Handle other content-types here or raise an Exception
        # if the content type is not supported.
        return request_body

def predict_fn(input_data, model):

    print("** predict_fn**")
    print("input_data: {} model:{}".format(input_data, model))
    print("\n")

    prefix = '/opt/ml/'
    model_path = os.path.join(prefix, 'model')
    my_vect = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_path, "vectorizer.joblib"))

    message = "".join(clean_token_pipeline(input_data))
    print("processed message: {}".format(message))
    message = my_vect.transform([message])
    message = message.toarray()
    prediction = model.predict(message)
    return prediction
```

Comment: It seems like that you're using the SDK correctly. Without looking at the data is hard to say what's going wrong. Is it possible to describe the Transform Job to see if the filter has been applied correctly? If there’s anything wrong applying the filter, the job should fail with client error and there’ll be logs in your CloudWatch account

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was because i was using local mode. For some reason, the output filter does not get used when running batch transform locally.